# Android byte type comparing

Tags: c#, android, byte

My code works on PC but only has problem when I run this on Android.
(Unity3d c#)

```
byte[] arr1;
byte[] arr2 = new byte[19];

arr1=readfrombuffer(); // read bytes from bluetooth device 
arr2 = arr1; //put value with for()

print(arr2[1].toString()); // works well (255)

if(arr2[1]==255)
{
         print("yes"); //never print   <- problem
}
```

---

`if(arr2[1]==255) , if(arr2[1]==(byte)255) , if(arr2[1]==0xFF)` ... still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Change **FROM**

```
if(arr2[1]==255)
{
         print("yes"); //never print   <- problem
}
```

**TO**

```
if(arr2[1].toString() == 255)
{
         print("yes"); //never print   <- problem
}
```

Comment: I tried  if(arr2[1].toString() == "255" but still not works

Comment: if `print(arr2[1].toString()); // works well (255)` this `arr2[1].toString() == 255` should work well too.